# C# / SQL Server : MVVM insert data into multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, mvvm

I work on a small project just to get to understand the mvvm model in C# better.
I work with a Microsoft SQL Server database with three tables: `customer`, `location` and `address`.

Every customer can have one or more locations, and every location has a specific address.

My current thought how to accomplish this:

- First insert the customer.
- To insert the location, get the highest `customer_id` and insert the location with the `max(customer_id)`
- Then, to insert the address, get the `max(location_id)` and insert the address, with the location id

Is there a better way to do this?

I haven't found any tutorial with an example of inserting data into more than one table, especially not using SQL Server.

And my next problem is: what should I bind to my TextBoxes, so that I can insert the content of it?

I thought about having a save button. This button would then execute a method, where I insert the data from the bound TextBoxes. Should I do this with commands, instead of writing a method?

Thanks already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql server has a `OUTPUT` clause which you can use

something like

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES({CustomerName})
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
```

then you can store the inserted customer's actual ID and do the rest inserts in separate queries.

As for your second question yes you should do it with Command binding to a method in your View model

Answer (score 1):

The most advisable for your situation is to use a transaction.

Example.- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx